A uniqueness theorem for regions containing dielectrics
Problem 4.40 from 'Introduction to Electrodynamics (Fifth edition)' By David J. Griffiths proves the following statement:
"A volume V contains a specified free charge distribution, and various pieces of linear dielectric material, with the susceptibility of each one given. If the potential is specified on the boundaries S of V then the potential throughout V is uniquely determined."
Following a method of proof similar to the proof of the second uniqueness theorem given in the same book on page 121, I have managed to prove the above statement and also prove that the potential is uniquely determined if either potential or its normal derivative are specified on each point on the boundary (with at least one point on S having potential specified) in the same situation given above.
My understanding is that I can assume a certain potential U within the region and conclude that it is the unique potential of a region V (with boundary S) if it satisfies a couple of conditions. Intuitively, my thoughts are that those conditions are:

Fulfilment of poisson's equation by U in regions within V containing volume charge distributions.
Meeting boundary potential/normal derivative conditions at S as specified above.
At a surface charge distribution within V, fulfilling the condition that $\varepsilon_{above}
E_{normal,above}-\varepsilon_{below}
E_{normal,below}=\sigma_{f}$ ($\sigma_f$ is free charge density) and $U_{above}-U_{below}=0$ (continuity of potential).

I wish to know if these conditions are sufficient to determine a unique U. Why or why not?
